# How to run Azure databricks notebook in a different subscription

Tags: python, azure

Our team has a Azure Databricks notebook written in Python that loads data from an external source into a data store. The business team has a Databricks notebook that reads that newly loaded data and does some analysis on it.

The business team wants our notebook to call their notebook once it's finished.

*Their notebook is in subscription: biz-subscription-test*

*in a resource collection called: biz-processing*

*and the notebook is in workflows->jobs and is called Price Simulator*

I'm trying to use the %run command, but I'm not sure how to specify the notebook path. Our notebook is in a different subscription and obviously in a different resource collection.

How can I specify the path? Or is this not possible with %run?

Comment: To run a Databricks notebook in a different subscription, you can use the %run command with an absolute path. In this case, you would need to provide the full path to the notebook in the other subscription's resource collection. For example, if the notebook is located at /Users/username@organization.com/directory/notebook in the biz-subscription-test subscription's biz-processing resource collection, you would use the following command in your notebook: `%run /Users/username@organization.com/directory/notebook`
You'll need to have appropriate permissions to access notebook in other sbscrptn